# Возможно создать docker image, чтобы не было возможности залогиниться в контейнер без пароля?

Tags: docker

Возможно создать docker image, чтобы не было возможности залогиниться в контейнер без пароля?

Это при том, что можно сделать следующее:

docker exec -it -u root container_name

docker attach container_name

Для чего это нужно.
Хост установлен у клиента, хост не котнролируется - он может залогиться под пользователем группы docker или рутом. Соотвественно можно залогигиться в контенер и что-то исправить, удалить, добавить, отправить неверные данные и т.д.
А вот хотелось бы запретить это делать...

Comment: Это невозможно. Пока клиент имеет полный доступ к своему собственному железу, он может делать со своим железом всё что угодно в обход любых защит.

Answer (score 1):

«что-либо исправить, удалить, добавить» можно вообще без обращения к программе *docker*: все файлы/каталоги образов и контейнеров располагаются (по умолчанию) в [`/var/lib/docker`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25978888/4827341).

никакого «контроля доступа» к содержимому этого каталога ни в клиентской программе *docker*, ни в программе-демоне *dockerd* не предусмотрено. да это было бы и невозможно реализовать.

если вам требуется «контроль доступа» к тем данным, которыми манипулирует ваша программа, помещённая внутрь образа, то и реализуйте этот контроль средствами вашей программы. хотя это, конечно, тоже далеко не «серербрянная пуля»: дизассемблеры (для программ) и hex-редакторы (для не-текстовых данных) вполне себе существуют и используются.